# C++ - Proper way to mock/expect Direct3dX - Google Test/Mock

Tags: c++, pointers, directx, googletest, googlemock

I'm creating a unit test for a class that uses DirectX3d9 Windows API calls.

Snippet of the class:

```
Screem::Screen()
{
    d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
}

HRESULT Screen::Init(void)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    hr = d3d->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, &mode);
    hr = d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, NULL, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &parameters, &device));
    hr = device->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(desktopWidth, desktopHeight, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &surface, nullptr));
    //more codes
}

class Screen
{
public:
    Screen();
    virtual ~Screen();
    virtual HRESULT Init(void);

protected:
    CComPtrCustom<IDirect3D9> d3d;
    CComPtrCustom<IDirect3DDevice9> device;
}
```

And my test goes something like this:

```
class ScreenTest: public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    void SetUp()
    {
        sut_ = std::make_unique<Screen>();
        d3dMock_ = std::make_unique<Direct3D9Mock>();
        d3dDeviceMock_ = std::make_unique<Direct3DDevice9Mock>();
    }

protected:
    std::unique_ptr<Screen> sut_;
    std::unique_ptr<Direct3D9Mock> d3dMock_;
    std::unique_ptr<Direct3DDevice9Mock> d3dDeviceMock_;
};

TEST_F(ScreenTest, Init_handleMocks)
{
    //Save actual ptr to a variable first
    auto d3dFromSut = sut_->d3d;

    sut_->d3d = d3dMock_.get();
    sut_->device = d3dDeviceMock_.get();

    EXPECT_CALL(*d3dMock_, GetAdapterDisplayMode(_, _)).WillOnce(Return(S_OK));
    EXPECT_CALL(*d3dMock_, CreateDevice(_, _, _, _, _, _)).WillOnce(Return(S_OK));
    EXPECT_CALL(*d3dDeviceMock_, CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(_, _, _, _, _, _)).WillOnce(Return(S_OK));
    EXPECT_EQ(S_OK, sut_->Init());

    // Save original d3d to sut_->d3d else Release() will generate an exception
    sut_->d3d = d3dFromSut;
}
```

So the mock actually works now. But my problem is, I get an exception when class CComPtrCustom destructor is called - since it calls Release().  Looks like it can't release `d3dDeviceMock_` - maybe because it is a smart pointer?

I can't do this:

```
auto d3dDevice = sut_->device;   //This saves NULL in d3dDevice since  device was only filled in CreateDevice()
```

then later on do this:

```
sut_->device = d3dDevice;   //This puts NULL back
```

Help!

Comment: It looks like an ownership problem, without relation to libraries. You currently have 2 owners of `d3dMock_` object - `sut_` owns it and releases it (as you described), but `ScreenTest` also owns it via `unique_ptr` and will try to `delete` it. You need to clarify which class should be the owner of object (i.e. which one will `delete` it and when).

Comment: I'm not sure how `CComPtrCustom` works, but I believe that it is also smart pointer, then doing something like `sut_->d3d = d3dMock_.get();` is very bad idea... Why you use `std::unique_ptr` instead of `CComPtrCustom` there?

Comment: d3dMock_ appears to work correctly (due to the hack I did of assigning original ptr to ```d3dFromSut``` and reloading it in ```sut_->d3d``` just before teardown. Where I am having so much trouble is in ```d3dDeviceMock_```. I tried using a ```shared_ptr``` for it but this generates an error: ```sut_->device = d3dDeviceMock_```.  If I use ```sut_->device = d3dDeviceMock_.get();``` then of course reference count does not increase. I tried ```CComPtrCustom<Direct3DDevice9Mock>``` but I am getting linker errors as of now :(

Comment: What is the point of this test? Test that `Init` does call all those methods is worthless because it is just straight copypasting. `sut_->d3d = d3dMock_.get();` should not compile because that field is protected. What is CComPtrCustom?

Comment: ```CComPtrCustom``` is just ```CComPtr``` with some customizations. But mostly just same as how the normal com ptr works.

Comment: Thoughts anyone?